# Cling: Looking for Opensource code for uPnp ContentDirectory

Tags: upnp, cling

I'm trying to build a uPnP control point for controlling audio and I am using Java the [cling library](https://github.com/4thline/cling). To browse the music on the server requires the [ContentDirectory](https://openconnectivity.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/UPnP-av-ContentDirectory-v1-Service.pdf) service, cling provides the api to access this but doesnt provide any classes to represent the various actions and arguments requiring me to write lots of boilerplate code, I wonder does such a library exist ?

For example Ive create a Browse class for the Browse action of a Content Directory

```
import org.fourthline.cling.model.meta.Action;
import org.fourthline.cling.model.types.UnsignedIntegerFourBytes;

public class Browse extends AbstractActionAndInvocation
{
    //INPUT
    public static final String OBJECT_ID        = "ObjectID";
    public static final String BROWSE_FLAG      = "BrowseFlag";
    public static final String FILTER           = "Filter";
    public static final String STARTING_INDEX   = "StartingIndex";
    public static final String REQUESTED_COUNMT = "RequestedCount";

    public void setObjectID(String objectID)
    {
        actionInvocation.setInput(OBJECT_ID, objectID);
    }

    public void setBrowseFlag(BrowseFlag browseFlag)
    {
        actionInvocation.setInput(BROWSE_FLAG, browseFlag.getParameterName());
    }

    public void setFilter(String filter)
    {
        actionInvocation.setInput(FILTER, filter);
    }

    public void setStartingIndex(int startingIndex)
    {
        actionInvocation.setInput(STARTING_INDEX, new UnsignedIntegerFourBytes(startingIndex));
    }

    public void setRequestedCount(int requestCount)
    {
        actionInvocation.setInput(REQUESTED_COUNMT, new UnsignedIntegerFourBytes(requestCount));
    }


    public Browse(Action action)
    {
        super(action);
    }
}
```

Since `ContentDirectory` only has a predefined list of Actions  it seems weird that these don't already exist somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the **cling-support** module there are useful classes such as callback classes for the main services

e.g

```
org.fourthline.cling.support.contentdirectory.callback.Browse.java;
```

However I found them to be of limited usefulness and serve more as an example implementation rather than one that can be used as is.